# How can I create a link under each picture in a post that uses info contained in each image's caption and description?

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have the following code to wrap any image inserted into a post into a set of divs (for styling purposes; see: http://natv.is/wp/). I would like to expand this so that underneath each photo, the text 'PHOTO CREDIT:' appears followed by the photographer's name (which is the content of the image's 'caption' box) as a hyperlink to the photographer's portfolio (which is the content of the image's 'description' box). Problem is, I am unsure how to call on the contents of those boxes or have them placed into the html. All the methods thus far have been to no avail. Any ideas?

```
function filter_images($content){
return preg_replace(
     '/<img (.*) \/>\s*/iU', '</div><div class="eightcol"><img \1 /></div><div class="onecol"></div><div class="sevencol">', $content);
} add_filter('the_content', 'filter_images');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use meta boxes
Just google WordPress meta boxes  and U will come to know
After that you can display the values by
Calling

```
  <?PHP the_meta(); ?>
```

IN UR template files 
 be back to me if U didn't get it